# Simple form: create multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

In my app I want to add feature to create several objects in one action:

on `localhost:3000/bank_accounts/new` I have a form for creating one object of `@bank_account`

```
= simple_form_for @bank_account do |f|
  = f.input :bank_name
  = f.input :account_number
  = f.button :submit
```

controller:

```
  def new
    @bank_account = BankAccount.new
  end

  def create
    @bank_account = BankAccount.create(bank_params)
    if @bank_account.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Is there a method to create several objects of `BankAccount` on `localhost:3000/bank_accounts/new`?

Comment: Try putting `@bank_account = BankAccount.new` in a `loop` something like `n.times do @bank_account = BankAccount.new end` where `n` is the number of `instances` you want to create.It may work if I'm correct.

Comment: @pavan with that loop you just write the same bank_account instance variable again and again. You should use #build, see my answerer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should follow a 'standard' way,
probably bank account belongs to a user, 
so you have a BankAccount that belongs to a User and a User has many BankAccounts.

In that case, in the controller you should have something like:

```
@user = User.find 1234 # get a user
10.times do
  @user.bank_accounts.build
end
```

and in the view you should use a loop to create the fields for all the user's bank accounts (you can user fields_for)

Finally, to create those bank accounts you can even use mass assignment with:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bank_accounts
```

I hope this can help :)